# Cordova $cordovaCapture.captureVideo quality is always low

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, video-capture

I'm trying to capture medium or high-quality video in Cordova.

The problem is that the captured video is always low quality (on my LG G3 Android device).

## First attempt - using $cordovaCapture

```
var options = { limit: 1, duration: 5, quality: 1 };

$cordovaCapture.captureVideo(options).then(function(videoData) {
  ...
});
```

## Second attempt - using videocaptureplus

```
window.plugins.videocaptureplus.captureVideo(
  function(mediaFiles) {
    ...
  },
  {
    limit: 1,
    duration: 5,
    highquality: true
  }
);
```

How can I capture medium or high quality videos from Cordova?

Answer (score 0):

Cordova uses 'quality' instead of 'highquality' as the quality. Set this to '1' for high quality. The official docs read:

*Android supports an additional quality property, to allow capturing video at different qualities. A value of 1 ( the default ) means high quality and value of 0 means low quality, suitable for MMS messages.*

source: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture